# how to create a list based on comma separated input

Tags: python

My script is taking the first argument as shown in the input below and I am trying to create a list out of it but incorrectly as shown in output, can anyone provide inputs on how to fix this?

```
projects = sys.argv[1]
ProjectList = list(projects)
```

INPUT:-

```
python script.py platform/system/bt,platform/packages/apps/Bluetooth,platform/vendor/qcom-proprietary/ship/bt/hci_qcomm_init
```

output:

```
['p', 'l', 'a', 't', 'f', 'o', 'r', 'm', '/', 's', 'y', 's', 't', 'e', 'm', '/', 'b', 't', ',', 'p', 'l', 'a', 't', 'f', 'o', 'r', 'm', '/', 'p', 'a', 'c', 'k', 'a', 'g', 'e', 's', '/', 'a', 'p', 'p', 's', '/', 'B', 'l', 'u', 'e', 't', 'o', 'o', 't', 'h', ',', 'p', 'l', 'a', 't', 'f', 'o', 'r', 'm', '/', 'v', 'e', 'n', 'd', 'o', 'r', '/', 'q', 'c', 'o', 'm', '-', 'p', 'r', 'o', 'p', 'r', 'i', 'e', 't', 'a', 'r', 'y', '/', 's', 'h', 'i', 'p', '/', 'b', 't', '/', 'h', 'c', 'i', '_', 'q', 'c', 'o', 'm', 'm', '_', 'i', 'n', 'i', 't']
```

Comment: You're going to want the split function:  https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.split

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking to use [split](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) here. And specify that you want to split on a comma:

```
ProjectList = projects.split(',')
```

Output:

```
['platform/system/bt', 'platform/packages/apps/Bluetooth', 'platform/vendor/qcom-proprietary/ship/bt/hci_qcomm_init']
```

Answer (score 0):

dont use list. it's better if you got with split()

```
ProjectList = projects.split(',')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split the string by using a delimiter see below:

```
projects = sys.argv[1]
ProjectList = projects.split(",")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call split method on project and assign it to a new variable.

ProjectList = project.split(',')

Answer (score 0):

Python has a built-in `split` method that takes a string and splits it into a list, splitting into new elements at specific delimiters. All you have to do is:

```
ProjectsList = projects.split(",")
```

You specify the delimiter within the parenthesis when you call split, in this case, a comma.